# Services custom GET operation

Tags: 7, services

How to create custom GET resource operation? I tried many variants in  `hook_services_resources()` but didn't find the solution. Is there way to do this?
I want get some data from url rest/coaching/objectives-info and it should be GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by adding new resource with index operation. So the path became 'rest/objectives-info', not he same but suitable.